# Authenticate with a backend server Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jwt, google-authentication, google-client

I have an android app while login it generates the idtoken

```
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
String idToken = acct.getIdToken();
```

Above ID token is json web token which should be verified from the application server. I have appengine backend app using Springs.So I wanted to verify this token in each of the restful webservice at backend.

As per google documentation

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

There are 3 approaches

1) To use custom approach e.g using JWT. In that case I was not able to identify the key to be used. Using https://jwt.io/. I pasted my jwt token and it was invalid signature.

2) To use google provided client libraries for Java
 I almost used same standard code proivded by google. I had reference to following links

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/01/using-google-sign-in-with-your-server.html

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lmoroney/serverauth/master/LmauthtestServlet.java

My Java code is like this
public class AuthenticateUtil {

```
private final GoogleIdTokenVerifier mVerifier;

public AuthenticateUtil() {

    NetHttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    GsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();

     mVerifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport,jsonFactory)  
               // Here is where the audience is set -- checking that it really is your server  
               // based on your Server’s Client ID  
              .setAudience(Arrays.asList("**My client ID"))  
               // Here is where we verify that Google issued the token  
              .setIssuer("https://accounts.google.com").build(); 
} 
public void verify(String idTokenString){
    System.out.println("idTokenString>>"+idTokenString);
    try {
        GoogleIdToken idToken = mVerifier.verify(idTokenString);
        if (idToken != null) {
            Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();
            System.out.println(payload.getSubject());
            } else {
              System.out.println("Invalid ID token.");
            }
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Inside exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Above code is giving exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:111)
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37)
at com.google.api.client.json.webtoken.JsonWebSignature$Parser.parse(JsonWebSignature.java:602)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken.parse(GoogleIdToken.java:57)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier.verify(GoogleIdTokenVerifier.java:191)
at com.AuthenticateUtil.verify(AuthenticateUtil.java:48)
```

3) To use the following google Token endpoint for verification

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={token}

It should not be used as it will require HTTP request from server and increase the latency to the client.

I want a solution on How to verify the integrity of the jwt token generated by android client on the backend server in java.

Comment: I am stuck on the same error. Were you able to resolve this ?